# Advice for Interview Burnout

Tags: interviewing, burnout

I'm currently going through an extended period of job-hunting and as such I'm having a lot of interviews and finding them and the questions I'm being asked very repetitive. What are some strategies for keeping energy, enthusiasm and the quality of my interview performance high while in this situation?

Comment: This is the third question - will you be deleting this one as well? I made an effort earlier to edit the formatting for you on the previous question.

Answer (score 6):

I had a five hour interview on day and the next day it was a seven hour interview. The interview consisted of one hour per team member or manager asking me questions at both interviews. I know what you mean by feeling burnt out. A lot of them asked me the same questions and I felt like a broken record.

I would keep a mentality of you wanting a job and would do anything to get that job, even if it means you have to repeat yourself a million times. Focus more on getting something done. What you can do physically is get a lot of sleep and just do anything that helps you relax like taking a nap (I drink tea, that helps a lot). @jcmack in their answer mentioned that you should keep up good health, which is a really nice idea. Exercise does make you extremely confident mentally.

Don't stress on what you did during your previous interviews and what was being asked. Thinking about your previous interviews make you paranoid and anxious.

@neubert in the comments had a good point. Seeing new people at new places should fill you up with excitement! "Wow there are lot of different people interested in me!" Be optimistic about new opportunities. The fact that you're even getting an interview should be a blessing since that shows they're interested in you and they want to get to know you more.

There's a lot of things in life that we do on a constant basis that we don't like doing like yard work and eating refrigerated leftovers that don't taste as good as when you made it fresh.

Answer (score 5):

> What are some strategies for keeping energy, enthusiasm and the quality of my interview performance high while in this situation?

Interviewing is hard work. There is no shame giving yourself a week off to recharge. Remember to eat good foods, exercise, and all that good stuff for your own mental and physical health.

But I think there might be a deeper problem here. Are you being strategic in your applications and interviews? The blitz style of interviewing (i.e. leave-no-stone-unturned and apply-to-everything style) can lead to burnout very quickly and isn't necessary more efficient than a strategic style. At this point you've probably calibrated enough to know which positions will be a good fit. I recommend:

- reducing the number of applications you submit by doing more upfront homework about the positions and the company
- prepreparing a list of questions you want answered for the initial phone screen
- don't continue to interview for positions or companies you are not interested in
- use services that turn the tables and have employers seek you out (e.g. Hired).

Comment: While "being strategic in your applications" is a good piece of advice in theory, operationalising it is often very difficult. For most of people a job is a compromise. If I rejected every job with red flags, I would be a long-term unemployed. Experts in some, extremely attractive, fields can afford it maybe, but most people don't. That's why normally, it makes sense to compare different companies to have a reality check and chose the best option. Not to mention that attending some interviews for jobs I wasn't super interested in, helped me to boost my confidence.

Comment: @BigMadAndy I think that makes sense. You could have kind of a calibration phase where you just pursue a ton of opportunities even ones you are not sure about and practice doing interviews. But depending on the individual this is just not sustainable in the long run. Hence the suggestion to dial back and be more selective.